# How to add verse-specific dynamic to sheet music

Tags: sheet-music, dynamics

I have lyrics of two verses below the staves.

[image: image of staff with two verses below]

Now I want the second verse to get the fortissimo (ff) dynamic. Now how do I do that? How is that written down in sheet music?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way to notate that would be f-ff (or "whatever the first dynamic is"-ff). The idea is that the first time you would play at the first dynamic and the second time you would play the second dynamic.

I would advise if there are any other modifications to the verse like crescendos, decrescendos, and accents the verses be separate so the texture change is clear.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this many times.

Answer (score 3):

2nd time ff.

2nd × ff.

Or, even better, the same in italian, which I *think* would be

2<sup>a</sup> volta ff

Comment: Unless the choir / vocalist is Italian or you live in Italy, the 3rd option would only be confusing.

Comment: Most indications on a sheet music already are in italian. Why not that one?

Comment: @Édouard: Most musicians do not know Italian; rather, they know some musical terms which happen to come from that language.  Your last example is not among the terms most musicians would know.

Comment: It is, however, obvious enough that everyone should get it. After all, everyone doesn’t speak english either, and we all struggle with a bit of italian from time to time (my former wind band got stuck on a *stringendo*, once).

Comment: I've seen "2x tacet" in scores; presumably just "2x ff" would work too.

Comment: @Édouard: I had no idea what it meant.

Comment: I have seen 'seconda volta' often enough.I'm not Italian but could read it. If I hadn't been able to read it I had consulted my invaluable book 'strange words in music', a book every musician should own (or an equivalent). I am sure I would have found it in there.

Comment: '2x ff' would be confusing for me, I normally interpret '2x ff' as 'two times fortissimo', instead of 'second time: fortissimo'. I prefer using '2nd ×' or something.